# grid layout with different grid heights using Fluid Baseline Grid

Tags: javascript, css

I am using this template: http://fluidbaselinegrid.com/ to create fluid grid to layout my personal site. Not all my grids are the height and I sometimes get the wrong placement.
[image: screenshot][1].

The skills section should be on the left under Blog Post 5 and Contact should be next to skills.

Please see my site at http://vsrao.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com. And you should be able to access the css and html there. I would be too long to paste it in this post. Please let me know if this is bad etiquette. Also let me know if there is a better fluid grid framework that is upto date.

Comment: I think you have to reduce the height of the skills section.

Comment: Obviously I know I can do that. But I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Perhaps not elegant but a fast and functional one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably tackle this by applying a clear: left via an nth-child selector on your columns. Using your media-queries, you should be able to mimic 2 or 3 column layouts like so:

```
// 2 column layout
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .g1:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}

// 3 column layout
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 .g1:nth-child(3n+1) {
        clear: left;
      }
}
```

Note: You'll need to add a new media-query (max-width: 767px) so the clear on 2 column layout only gets applied to your smaller screen view.